# Run a Python script with filename arguments as a MacOS Folder action

Tags: macos, shell-script, automator, python3

I would like to run a Python script as a Folder Action in Mac OS.  The Python script takes the name and full path of a file as an argument. Ideally, I would like to right-click on a file in Finder to launch the Folder Action, taking the name of the file as the first argument and the path as the second argument. But I can't figure out how to load the two variables in Automator.

This is the furthest that I have been able to get,

[image: AutomatorScreenCap]

where `$1` should be the filename, and `$2` should be the full path of the file.

Does anybody have any hints for how to do this?

Comment: can you post your code? also it might help more to post this on Stackoverflow instead of SuperUser

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working for my use case, but I only used a filename.

```
~/anaconda3/bin/python <path to python script> "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess you likely have a solution already, but `basename` will allow you to get the filename from the path, e.g.:

```
/path/to/python /path/to/script.py "$(basename $1)" "$1"
```